# Passing variable using url Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have problem in variable $data Model.
I will show the system screen with the result.

[This is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ7hE.jpg)

My Model:

```
public function get_aqui($id=NULL){
    if ($id !=NULL):
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('financeiroaquiler as f');
        $this->db->join('aluguel as a', 'f.aluguel_id_alug = a.id_alug');
        $this->db->join('usuarios as u', 'u.id_usu = a.inquilino_id_inqui');
        $this->db->join('apartamento as d', 'd.id_apart = a.apartamento_id_apart');
        $this->db->where('a.id_alug', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('');

        if ($query-> num_rows ()> 0) {
            foreach ($query-> result_array () as $row) {
                $data [] = $row;
                var_dump($row);
            }
        }
        $query-> free_result();
       return $data;
    else:
        set_msg('msgerro', 'error', 'erro');
    endif;
}
```

My Controller:

```
 public function pagos($id){       
    $this->sindico->get_aqui($id);
    set_tema('titulo', 'Lista de Pagos Aquillers');
    set_tema('conteudo',  load_modulo('aquiler', 'pagos'));
    load_template();
}
```

My view:

```
 <?php
             $dados['album'] = $this->sindico->get_aqui();
             if (count($dados['album'])){
             foreach ($dados['album'] as $linha) {
                 echo '<tr>';
                 printf('<td>%s / %s</td>', ($list['id_alug']) ?: '/', ($linha->nome_usu));
                 printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->data_pagamento);
                 printf('<td>%s</td>', "Bs" . $linha->valor_pagamento);
                 printf('<td>%s</td>', $linha->status_pagamento);
                 printf('<td class="text-center">%s</td>', '<div class="btn-group"><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-xs dropdown-toggle"  data-original-title="" title="">Action<span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right"><li><a href="editar/' . $linha->id_finan . '">Edit</a></li><li><a href="excluir/' . $linha->id_finan . '">Delete</a></li>');
                 echo '</tr>';
             }}
             ?>
```

Look get_aqui function. Where the variable $data is in trouble .

Answer (score 0):

**MODAL**

```
 public function get_aqui($id=NULL){
        if ($id !=NULL):
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('financeiroaquiler as f');
            $this->db->join('aluguel as a', 'f.aluguel_id_alug = a.id_alug');
            $this->db->join('usuarios as u', 'u.id_usu = a.inquilino_id_inqui');
            $this->db->join('apartamento as d', 'd.id_apart = a.apartamento_id_apart');
            $this->db->where('a.id_alug', $id);
           return $query = $this->db->get('')->result();

        else:
            set_msg('msgerro', 'error', 'erro');
        endif;
    }
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function pagos($id){       
    $data['result']=$this->sindico->get_aqui($id);
    set_tema('titulo', 'Lista de Pagos Aquillers');
    set_tema('conteudo',  load_modulo('aquiler', 'pagos'));
    load_template();
}
```

now you can use  $result-> **table_coloum_name**  in view file by passing

```
 $this->load->view('**view_file_name**',$data['result']); in conroller
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in

Comment: you want me to put this line in view? $this->load->view('**view_file_name**',$data['result']); in conroller

Comment: put this line  $this->load->view('view_file_name',$data['result']);  in conroller and you can use $result->coloum_name   for fetch data in view